# Concatenating filename and filepath, path is splitted?

Tags: c, filepath, string-concatenation

I have a program, that expects a file path and a part of the file name as input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[3][50];

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int run;
    run=atoi(argv[2]);

    char *datapath=malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    datapath=argv[1];

    sprintf(filename[0], "%s/test1.run%i", datapath, run);
    sprintf(filename[1], "%s/test2.run%i", datapath, run);
    sprintf(filename[2], "%s/test3.run%i", datapath, run);

}
```

But the resulting filename is separated to two strings. One containing

```
Name : filename
    Details:{"/home/test/data", "/test.run1", '\0' <repeats 74 times>, '\0' <repeats 49 times>}
```

Why?

Comment: First of all your malloc will cause a memory leak, you are not using that memory block(actually no need to allocate memory as you are using argv[1]).
And is that your entire code? I think there is something missing.

Comment: datapath=argv[1] just updates the datapath pointer to point to the argv char array at index 1. This results in the address of the malloced memory to be lost

Comment: Your `Details:{"/home`.... line is bogus (i.e. it doesn't represent what your code does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem. I modified your code a little bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[3][50];

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int run;
    run=atoi(argv[2]);

    char *datapath=argv[1];

    sprintf(filename[0], "%s/test1.run%i", datapath, run);
    sprintf(filename[1], "%s/test2.run%i", datapath, run);
    sprintf(filename[2], "%s/test3.run%i", datapath, run);

    printf("filename[0]=%s\n", filename[0]);
    printf("filename[1]=%s\n", filename[1]);
    printf("filename[2]=%s\n", filename[2]);

}
```

And then ran it:

```
$ gcc h.c -o h
$ ./h /home/test/data 1
filename[0]=/home/test/data/test1.run1
filename[1]=/home/test/data/test2.run1
filename[2]=/home/test/data/test3.run1
```

This is what you expected, right?

Comment: Yes I added code to print out the three filepaths. This is what you are seeing. But this shows that each resulting filename is not separated to two strings like you said (there is no extra newline in each filename)

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy a string in this way.

Change:

```
char *datapath=malloc(100*sizeof(char));

datapath=argv[1];
```

to

```
char *datapath = malloc(100); // don't cast malloc, and sizeof(char) is always 1

strcpy(datapath, argv[1]); /* datapath is writeable */
```

or

```
char *datapath = argv[1]; /* datapath is read only */
```

You can take a look to "Characters and Strings" section of [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

oh - I just found out that I allocated filename too small! I'm sorry for the silly question!

(my filepath is much longer than this test-example)